# Click event on a dynamic link with bootstrap and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have some javascript code (jquery and bootstrap) for the link `myLink` that has to display [a popover](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers). In that popover, I format some html code to be displayed and in that html I add a button link `myButtonLink`.

So when user clicks on the `myLink`, it shows the popover.

And when user clicks on the `myButtonLink` inside the popover, I want to execute `window.open(url, 'pages', opts);` where `url` is the target of `myButtonLink` and `opts` contains some information to display the window.

The first time an user clicks on `myLink`, everything is allright : popover is shown and the `myButtonLink` calls the javascript code:

```
$('.myLink').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open(this.href, 'pages', opts);
    return false;
});
```

But the second time, the user do the same things but above javascript code is not executed. I guess the event is no more triggered, but why?

Is this a case to use the `onclick` attribute on `<a />`?

***N.B.: This question is complex without an example and my example is too ugly to be understood... So tell me if you need more details.***

Comment: Is the popup still open? Since you gave it a name, it will open the page in the same window. Can you check if that is the case?

Comment: Can you provide of [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of what you currently have?

Comment: When it does not execute the javascript code, it opens the page in the same window.

Comment: Is the popup still open? No, I use the trigger `manual` to let me control the open/close behavior of multi `myLink`: one is open/shown, eveything but this one are closed/hidden.

Comment: I tried, but it does not work because of bootstrap... As you can see in http://jsfiddle.net/TWQ4S/